# Properly handling touches with multiple views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, hittest

I currently have a project where I present a HUD using this control:

https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

I present the SVProgress HUD over a complicated hierarchy of UIViews and ScrollViews.

SVProgressHUD is a bit like a UIAlertView, it presents a message but it auto dismisses itself.

In one part of my app, I am using it each time the user pops through a page in my UIScrollView.

The autodismiss feature is good but I want the user to be able to tap the hud and dismiss it early if required.

So I know SVProgressHUD posts a notification to notification center

```
SVProgressHUDDidReceiveTouchEventNotification
```

This is good, and what i've done is add a notification observer in my main viewController which calls a class method on SVProgressHUD to dismiss any presented HUD's when the `SVProgressHUDDidReceiveTouchEventNotification` is posted.

My problem (and question is) how can I ensure this dismiss method doesn't interfere with my scrollview?

I want my users to be able to quickly swipe through scrollview content pages, however since I started listening to this notification the scrollview doesn't react to the **first** touch of the user, it uses the first touch to dismiss the HUD. This feels quite clunky.

The problem is `SVProgressHUDDidReceiveTouchEventNotification` is being posted even if the HUD isn't touched and instead my Scrollview underneath is touched. How can I add a hittest inside my dismiss method to check that `SVProgressHUDDidReceiveTouchEventNotification` was posted because the HUD itself was touched?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling the dissmiss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented `touchesEnded` in **SVProgressHUD** and handle touches there.